# Linking affiliate id to woocommerce order detail admin page

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

i'm having trouble with something:
I'm using ultimate affiliate pro as my affiliate network and woocommerce (as a contact form) to generate leads.
I've managed to add in the 'order detail wp wooc admin area' an 'Affiliate' custom meta, but i'm having trouble automaticly linking the affiliate here.
This is the code :

```html
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 ); 

function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){ 
echo '<p><strong>'.__('Affiliate').':</strong> <br/>' . get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'uap_landing_page_affiliate_id', true ) . '</p>'; 
}
```

Question is :
How do i set uap_landing_page_affiliate_id ?
My current id is : www.mywebsite.com/checkout/?ref=AFFILIATE-NAME-HERE
so i need to set uap_landing_page_affiliate_id = AFFILIATE-NAME-HERE , before that function..
Any help would be much appreciated, thankyou!

Comment: Doesn't the plugin already take care of setting the `uap_landing_page_affiliate_id`. I don't understand why you are trying to set this too?

Comment: i have the option to add it manually, i'm trying to add it automaticly!
1. client clicks on banner arrives on landing page with the affiliate link, inserts the data, clicks send, lead created.
2. in my woocommerce admin order page under billiing info i want this to track that automaticly!
in this moment uap_landing_page-affiliate-id is empty/does not show, only if i add it manualy!

Comment: You'll want to talk with whomever created the Ultimate Affiliate Pro plugin about how to do this.